# Can I get the IP address of the client and server making a request from my web server?

Tags: apache, ip, referrer

If I had a webserver that was serving up some content through an iFrame to another webserver can I get the IP address of the client and the other server?

Example: A webserver "W" gets a request from client "C" for a webpage that loads an iFrame with content from my webserver "M". Can I get the IP address of "P" and "W"

Answer (score 0):

iFrames are client components. By embedding an iFrame in HTML served by your web server, you only tell the client's browser to make an additional request (and maybe more subsequently) to the URL in the iFrame's `src` attribute. On the server, you only have the request's referrer as a hint if it could have come from an iFrame tag (unless if you perform some checking in the HTML you send, but I guess that is beyond the scope of your question).

IP addresses will always be from the requesting client, but not from that other server.